# How to correctly use 2 PSUs in a multi-GPU server

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, gpu, pci-express

I am in the process of building a personal multi-gpu server for deep learning projects. Currently, I have 4x 4090 and 2x 1600W Superflower Titanium PSUs. The GPUs will be connected to the motherboard with LINKUP PCI-E 4.0 X16 cables (https://linkup.one/extreme4-pcie-4-0-x16-riser-cable-straight/) and the PSUs will be connected with an Add2PSU adapter.

My question is, since there might be power coming in through the PCIe riser cables via the motherboard, and 2 of the GPUs will have power cables coming from a different PSUs, does this create any conflicts or the possibility of a short?

Please correct me if anything I say is incorrect. I don't have much background in this type of stuff and I want to learn.

Answer (score 0):

I have three motherboards where I have 3x 4090´s on one power supply and 3x 4090´s on another. I've not had an issue. From what I've read just make sure the grounding on both is the same, so make sure you have a proper grounding where you are installing them.

I´ve been looking for something similar to have 2 power supplies interconnected, I haven't found it so far, search "power supply distribution boards" on eBay.

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you need:

- [24 Pin Main Second Dual PSU ATX Power Supply Motherboard Adapter Cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07543LNRH)

It will synchronize your two power supplies.

[image]

Comment: Why would they need this? What is the explanation? Link only answers are frowned upon here.